# Spring Security with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to create a Spring Boot REST application. When I deploy my application, it authentication is required and it is asking me for user name and password. How can I bypass this or how can I add a user name and password for authentication?

Do I need to remove security entry in pom?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of removing security from `pom.xml`. In your project, you can try something like below. Try to create `SecurityConfig` which will extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and provide some user name and password and later you can customize it.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                    .password("user")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .and()
                .withUser("user2")
                    .password("secret2")
                    .roles("USER");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http
            .httpBasic();
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

---

```java
public @interface EnableWebMvcSecurity {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use authentication at all, you should remove the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

See [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security):

> If Spring Security is on the classpath then web applications will be secure by default with ‘basic’ authentication on all HTTP endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other two answers -  default username is 'user' and password will be printed in the console each time you start your server like below -

```
2019-08-31 23:58:16.417  INFO 12528 --- [  restartedMain] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 1ab46edf-332a-42de-ae11-70dc138c65db
```

Simply use these credentials to login.

**Note** - If you fine-tune your logging configuration, ensure that the `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security` category is set to log INFO-level messages. Otherwise, the default password is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to configure a username/password of your choice then you can do so in **application.properties** file.

spring.security.user.name=username

spring.security.user.password=password

Now spring security will not generate a new password each time you boot the application.

Note: When using postman to send requests, go to authorization> select "basic auth"> Enter the username and password so authentication details can be sent along with each request. If using browser, there should be a login page.